Adding Previous and Next Month dates in Angular Mat-Calendar
Is this possible to show previous and next months dates from first and last week of the current month in the Angular Mat Calendar. Please see picture for reference.
Calendar
I am unable to find anything related to this, Is creating a custom calendar the only way?

Since this "space" is used to show the month, it's impossible. anothers datepickers like in ng-bootstrap have this option, but not in material-angular. NOTE: To know how makes a custom calendar you can take inspiration from this SO

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
